# Web applet that can save data

Tags: javascript, applet

I did some fairly basic programming many years ago, but I'm very rusty. I want to program a pretty basic web applet, and I want it to be able to save data. Think of it as a very simple game, and think that I want the game to be able to save the scores of the various players, so that I would be able to go somewhere and see the list of scores. (Except I want the data to be a little more complicated than the just one number, and I want it to be saved as a .csv).

I was hoping that I can write it as a java applet. Was that too sanguine? What is the easiest way to program such a thing? I don't anything fancy, just the easiest possible way to do it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: That time many years ago was the time when writing applets was considered a reasonable way to do things in web browsers.  The time has passed. There are ways (in modern browsers) to persist state in client-side storage via JavaScript and new APIs.

Comment: Can you direct me to a place where I can learn the very minimum I need to to do that?

Comment: Wait, do you want one database of all players' scores, or a way to store one player's score locally?  If the former, you could not do it with client-side storage APIs.

Comment: Sure: [here is the Mozilla page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) about DOM storage.  If you google for "html5 web storage" or similar phrases, you should find zillions of sources.

Comment: And yes, what @JeffB says is true: client-side storage is useful for client-specific data. Global data like the list of *all* player scores would be something you'd keep on a centralized server.

Comment: I see. Yes, I do want to have the information of all users for myself. Is there a way to do this stuff completely in java?

Comment: *"just the easiest possible way to do it"*  If that is the case, avoid the applet completely and launch a frame from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info). *"Is there a way to do this stuff completely in java?"* then you'll need some server side functionality to accept the scores and store them.  Do you have a Java enabled server, access to a DB?  BTW - I expect this task will be harder than you presume.

Answer (score 0):

Emm... If you want a conception... As I can get it, you can simply create

- A) The game applet
- B) Servlet project to deploy it right to the native applet host (not to have additional task as to sign it...);
- C) Write something in a way as HttpClient (of apache) to upload
  clients data from applet back to servlet (to have it saved or
  something);
- D) And, of course, make you servlet save the incomming data (maybe in
  a session or in a file whatever you like...)
- E) As you saying, you want to see all clients saved data or so... And
  then you can create a service or another applet to get the saved data
  and analyze it;

Report that helps